# How to delete corresponding row using ON DELETE CASCADE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 Tables, one known as "Image" Table, other known as "Image_Question" Table. Below is what the 2 tables could look like:

Image Table:

```
ImageId   ImageFile
01        picture/cat.png
02        picture/cat_2.png
03        picture/dog.png
```

Image_Question Table:

```
ImageId  SessionId  QuestionId
01            ADS            3
02            FTG            7
03            JJK            1
```

What my question is that in SQL how do I write it so that ImageId's from both tables are linked together so that lets say I delete row from Image Table where ImageId = 01, that the ImageId = 01 (corresponding row) from the Image_Question Table is also deleted.

I tried the code below but it did not work:

```
ALTER TABLE Image_Question ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ImageId FOREIGN KEY (ImageId) REFERENCES Image (ImageId) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

UPDATE:

SHOW IMAGE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE `Image` (
 `ImageId` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `ImageFile` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ImageId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=399 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

SHOW IMAGE_QUESTION TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE `Image_Question` (
 `ImageQuestionId` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `ImageId` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `SessionId` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `QuestionId` int(5) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ImageQuestionId`),
 KEY `QuestionId` (`QuestionId`),
 KEY `SessionId` (`SessionId`),
 KEY `fk_imagequestionid` (`ImageId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work?  Did it give an error?  Did you try deleting from the image_question table and it didn't delete from image table?

Comment: The deletion of data did not work?? OR  ALTER TABLE - addition of key did not work

Comment: The syntax of the query was fine, but when I delete a row from either table, it did not delete the corresponding row in the other table

Comment: What do you mean by either table..What you have given above should only delete corresponding rows from Image table..when ever a row is deleted from Image_Question table

Comment: Well even if I delete row from Image_Question table, it doesn't delete corresponding row in Image Table

Comment: Is it because the field ImageId in Image_Question Table is a primary key? Is that the reason why it isn't working?

Comment: 1, @RatanSharma is wrong. You set the foreign key constraint in the CHILD table. That is the table that will receive the cascading delete/update. It makes no sense at all to have `ImageId` as primary key for table `Image_Question`, but being a primary key doesn't affect the cascade as far as I know. As I mention in my answer, you're just using the wrong table type. Use InnoDB, not MyISAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only requirement for a foreign key is that it be an index, as far as I know. Your key in `Image_Questions` should be `QuestionId`, and it looks like you've changed it to that already per my suggestion in a comment. But that's not the reason your CASCADE DELETE doesn't work.

(A side note: as far as data organization goes, it makes no sense to have the same primary key for two tables in 99.9% of cases (only real case is to hide sensitive information like credit card numbers). If two tables have the same primary key, they should be the same table.)

Since you posted your `CREATE TABLE` statements, the problem is now totally obvious - only `InnoDB` supports foreign key constraints in MySQL. `MyISAM` does not (yet). It is strange and misleading that they let you create MyISAM tables with foreign key syntax without error and don't support it.

The way you have it set up, deleting a row from table Image will delete the corresponding row(s) in Image_Question. That makes sense.

Foreign Keys set up Parent->Child relationships. If you kill the parent, the child dies. But if you kill a child, that doesn't kill the parent. The parent will continue to exist, and may have many other children.

Each of your images might have 50 questions. You don't want to delete the parent image when any one of those child questions is deleted. But if you delete 1 image, all of its child questions become irrelevant and useless. You CAN cascade delete, but you could `SET NULL` or `NO ACTION` if you think the child data could still be useful in some way. SET NULL would render all `orphan` rows equal, whereas NO ACTION would keep their referent-less foreign keys and so you could still group them by parent even though the parent is gone.

This query should result in a cascade once you've changed your tables to InnoDB:

```
DELETE FROM `Images` WHERE `id` = 2;
```

That will delete **one** row from `Images` where id is 2 (since `id` is the primary key and only one row per value can exist), and ALSO **all** rows from `Image_Questions` where the `ImageId` is 2 (millions of rows could exist).

Also note that it's very weird for you to have `ImageId` as the first column of `Image_Questions` and it should NOT be the primary key. There is very rarely a reason to have two tables with the exact same primary key. The primary key of `Image_Questions` should be the `QuestionId`.

Refer to this for info on foreign key support in MySQL:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html

Here is a link to the ON DELETE options:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: So do you know what my sql should be? All it says when I include the above sql is your query was executed successfully. But it does not kill the row from the child table (Image_Question) if the row from parent table is killed (Image Table)

Comment: I will have to create a new field and call it ImageQuestionId and make that a primary key. Reason is that I cannot make QuestionId a primary key because multiple images can be in same question so there will be duplicate QuestionId's

Comment: It is still not delete the corresponding row from Image_Question Table when I delete a row from the Image Table

Comment: Please run "SHOW CREATE TABLE Image" and "SHOW CREATE TABLE Image_Questions" and edit your question adding the output. Then I can test it for myself.

Comment: I have updated question to include the "SHOW CREATE TABLE Image" and "SHOW CREATE TABLE Image_Questions"

Comment: See my "edit2" - MyISAM doesn't support foreign key trickery. Use InnoDB.